# Auto GET to argument of view

Tags: python, django, django-urls, django-views

```
some_view?param1=10&param2=20

def some_view(request, param1, param2):
```

Is such possible in Django?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always write a decorator.  Eg. something like (untested):

```
def map_params(func):
    def decorated(request):
        return func(request, **request.GET)
    return decorated

@map_params
def some_view(request, param1, param2):
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's possible to get it to pass them as *arguments* to the view function, but why can't you access the `GET` variables from `request.GET`? Given that URL, Django would have `request.GET['param1']` be 10 and `request.GET['param2']` be 20. Otherwise, you'd have to come up with some kind of weird regular expression to try and do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Paolo... the stuff after the '?' are GET parameters and should probably be treated as such.  That said, if you really want to keep the definition of some_view() as you've stated in the question, you could do something like:

```
from django.http import Http404
def some_view_proxy(request):
     if 'param1' in request.GET and 'param2' in request.GET:
         return some_view(request, request.GET['param1'],
                          request.GET['param2'])
     raise Http404
```

Or you could just define some_view() like this and use the GET params.  Just curious, why do you want that?

Comment: I need this cause - its use less code, i can maybe make a decorator for this

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fighting Django, why not just request some_view/10/20 and then set up urls.py to extract the arguments?

Comment: I am not fighting, it is my json service, jquery use params to send, many different and many not required. Thats why its easier.